# "Coming Soon" error

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-story-mode

I recently got MCSM for the PS4. Upon attempting to play Episode 2, it shows a message **Coming Soon** on it, despite Episode 2 existing for quite some time now. Upon going to Episodes, and trying to download, it says **Purchased & Coming Soon**. How do I fix it? The game is at it's latest version. Will I need an MCSM account to be able to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the game? it may just need some kind of download, or something failed

Comment: @dakre18 I could try. But I would like to keep that to a worst case, since it takes a long time. Are there any other suggestions that you could have?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but that's why I asked instead of put it as an answer.

Comment: @dakre18 Ok. I might just go with that redownload and I will report back once I can

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zONnsUXO6jA) was what you're talking about right?

Comment: Did you play Episode 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you complete Episode 1? As Telltale says, you need to complete **The Order of the Stone** so you can play Episode 2. If that doesn't work, try the following:

1. Reinstall the game.
2. Get a new disk and play the game (You won't start all over again. The progress is stored in the system of your PlayStation, not the disk. The disk is only for playing the game, not storing the data. It would've been more of a problem is data is stored inside the disk).
3. Log in (or sign up if you don't have an account) to Telltale if you haven't. This may cause a problem with the Episodes.
4. Turn off the game and PS4 and then return it on and play the game.

Okay now if those don't work, go to the Telltale website and ask them about the issues you have in support. They will work on the bug or give you a solution I don't have: https://www.telltalegames.com/community/categories/support

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but on PS3 turned out it was a region free disc but was still an United States copy (I'm in uk). I had to create a new psn account and set this one to US as location this then let me download the episodes 2-5 through the main menu of the game, then installed via PlayStation 3 home screen then changed back to my regular PSN account started story mode and they where there installed to play, I also deleted all my previous update and game save files before starting story mode on my US psn account not sure if this was necessary or not, I determined the disc region by its age rating dirrferent style to uk, hope this helps took all day to figure out